# How to use a Jinja variable in a HTML script?

Tags: python, html, scripting, jinja2

In my *application.py* I am doing a query and sending the results **rows** when rendering the html template:

```
rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM fase1 JOIN gamesf1 ON fase1.f1game_id = gamesf1.f1game_id WHERE user_id = :userid AND fase1.f1game_id = :f1gameid",
                  userid=request.args.get("u"), f1gameid=request.args.get("g"))

return render_template("updatef1.html", rows=rows)`
```

In my *html* file I am able to use the variables inside **rows** as follow and make a form using them:

```
{% for row in rows %}
  <h2>{{(row["f1game_team1"])}} vs. {{(row["f1game_team2"])}}</h2>
  <form action="/f1updated" id="f1update" method="post">
     <input type="number" class="form-control" id="marcadort1" name="marcadort1" value={{(row["marcador_t1"])}} min="0">
     ...
  </form>
{% endfor %}
```

And it works good.

The problem I have is when writing a script function() inside the same *for* loop:

```
<script>
   let form = document.getElementById("f1update");
   form.onsubmit = function() {
      if (form.marcadort1.value == 0 & form.marcadort2.value == 0 & form.primergol.value != "No Goles")
      {
        alert("Si no hay goles, no puedes tener un pais en PRIMER GOL");
        return false;
      }
      if (form.marcadort1.value == 0 &  form.primergol.value == {{(row["f1game_team1"}}))
      {
        alert("No puedes poner PRIMER GOL al pais que tenga marcado 0");
        return false;
      }
   };
</script>
```

The first *if* works fine since I am not using any variables. But the second if uses the variable **{{(row["f1game_team1"}}** and give me a **Parsing error: Unexpected token {**

Any help on how to use these variables inside the function script?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you not just miss the order of the parenthesis in this line?

```
if (form.marcadort1.value == 0 &  form.primergol.value == {{(row["f1game_team1"}}))
```

I think it should be

```
if (form.marcadort1.value == 0 &&  form.primergol.value == {{(row["f1game_team1"])}})
```

It is a good idea to initialize JavaScript variables form what you pass to the template, to allow for easier debugging, and avoid such traps.

Additionally, you should look up the difference between `&` and `&&` operators, as I am sure you did not mean what you wrote.

Comment: It was my mistake when pasting it here... I do have it `if (form.marcadort1.value == 0 &&  form.primergol.value == {{(row["f1game_team1"])}})` just made the && correction. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Maybe try to add quotes? `if (form.marcadort1.value == 0 && form.primergol.value == "{{(row["f1game_team1"])}}" )`